# How can I add a delay to a JS redirect

Tags: javascript

how can I add a time delay of 5 seconds to this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if (document.location.href.indexOf('url-wording') > -1) { 
    document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/'; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to delay it?

Comment: With setTimeout

Comment: I need a delay, so that a tracking pixel can fire. The direct redirect is too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('url-wording') > -1) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
  }, 5000); // 5000ms = 5s
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, because it looks correct, but it is not working. I am still
redirected directly.

Comment: Make sure that all browser cache is deleted, try to open your project in "Incognito Window" just to make sure there is no cache involved